# Amazon Linux 2 AMI - Can't access folder due to password

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to get a Postgresql (version 10.4) database up and running on my EC2 instance. I finally was able to access the psql interactive terminal through the bash terminal within my Linux instance. Now, I'm trying to get into my ec2-user folder to seed my database but I keep getting permission denied. I used `sudo cd ec2-user` to access it but I get hit with a message `[sudo] password for postgres:`. I didn't set up a password for postgres (not even sure why I need to enter a password here for postgres to access this folder). I ended up creating a password for the root role of psql but that doesn't work either. Does anyone know what password it's referring to here and why I need the password postgres to access my `ec2-user` folder? [image: Picture of my terminal]

Comment: You are logged in as `postgres`. Exit first this `postgres` session before you can sudo su to some other user.

Comment: Do I basically need to make another user account and login as that to my postgres?

Comment: After you `sudo su - postgres` you will be `postgres` user in your terminal. Just type `exit` to go back to `ec2-user`.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I need to provide more context. The only way to utilize psql is to login to the bash terminal through `sudo -i -u postgres`. I can't do any psql commands as the `ec2-user`. The reason I'm trying to access my `ec2-user` folder as the `postgres` user is to load a schema and some data into my database directly via `psql someTable -f database/postgres/schema.sql` which requires psql commands which I can't use as `ec2-user`. Hope that makes sense. That's the reason why I'm trying to get into that folder as the `postgres` user

Comment: There are few possibilities. Change permissions on ec2-user folder. Add postgres user to sudo file. Movie files that postgres user should access to postgres home folder or other folder accessible to postgres. Probably one could think of other possibilities.

Comment: "The only way to utilize psql is to login to the bash terminal through sudo -i -u postgres"  That is the only way to do it, only because you haven't configured another way.  Rather than trying to cram things into an unconfigured (well, default-configured) database, think a bit about how you want it configured, then implement it.